# How to undo changes matching a pattern in multiple commits?

Tags: git

I am working on a project where a large chunk of code was converted from C to C++. During the conversion process, multiple instances of the `restrict` keyword were removed in multiple commits.

Now, I want to undo all the removals of the `restrict` keyword, but the problem is that the commits responsible for the removal introduced some useful changes as well. Is there a way to create a patch that will only undo the removals of the `restrict` keywords (throughout the whole history) but nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the most recent commit `<id>` where `restrict` was not yet removed.
2. From the newest commit, where the port to C++ is completed, run

   ```
   $ git checkout -p <id>
   ```

   which will interactively prompt you to apply the individual changes in reverse.
3. Reject all hunks that are unrelated to `restrict` by entering `n`, accept all hunks that are related to `restrict` by entering `y`. If you are brave and it is necessary, enter hunk-editing mode by entering `e`. You should be able to directly jump to hunks containing `restrict` by doing a search using `/`.
4. If necessary, do manual cleanup afterwards.
5. Create a new commit from the staged changes which hopefully restore all occurrances of `restrict` as required.

Should this become too tedious you can abort the interactive part using `q`, and create a commit containing the work done so far. You can always squash them to a single, clean commit later.

#### Alternative approach

To pretend that the `restrict` keywords were never removed:

1. same as above
2. From the newest commit, create a new branch (in order to not lose the original branch), and rebase the port to C++:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b restore-restrict
   $ git rebase -i <id>
   ```
3. Mark all commits where `restrict` keywords were removed with `edit`.
4. For each commit to be edited, restore `restrict` either by manually editing the files or by `git checkout -p HEAD^` (similar to first approach, only on individual commits). Then,

   ```
   $ git commit --amend
   $ git rebase --continue
   ```